# Data JList and ComboBox from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I would to get data from selected value on the ComboBox by using MySQL. However, in the JList, it shows all the data form `songpick` column without get the value from the ComboBox. Is there anything wrong with my sql command?

`FillCombo()` method:

```
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from customer");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String CustomerName= rs.getString("customername");
            jComboBox1.addItem(CustomerName);
        }
```

`FillList()` method:

```
        DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select songpick from customer");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            String songpick=rs.getString("songpick");
            dlm.addElement(songpick);
            jList1.setModel(dlm);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if your filtered the result set from the database by the customer's name, for example...

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
try (PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select songpick from customer where customername=?")) {
    String customerName = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    st.setString(1, customerName);
    try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {

            String songpick = rs.getString("songpick");
            dlm.addElement(songpick);

        }
        jList1.setModel(dlm);
    }
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

*ps: I don't know you database structure, so I'm only guessing at the relationships*

You should also take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details about how to manage your resources and the [SQL Where Clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `WHERE` clause and set the value that you want to get from

E.g. `SELECT songpick FROM customer WHERE <columnName> = ?` and set the value of the  that you need before the `executeQuery` statement with `st.setString(1, "Foo");`